# Проверка элемента перед добавлением в массив

Tags: java

Есть пустой массив `String[] list`, как в цикле перед добавлением проверить на дублирование, если нет такого элемента тогда добавить

Comment: Использовать вместо массива хешсет.

Comment: Если не сложно приведите пожалуйста примером

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Есть специальный тип коллекции, который не допускает наличие дубликатов - [HashSet](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashSet.html)

В примере добавим дубликаты в коллекцию

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Set<String> uniqueStrings = new HashSet<>();

    uniqueStrings.add("one");
    uniqueStrings.add("two");
    uniqueStrings.add("three");

    uniqueStrings.add("one");
    uniqueStrings.add("two");
    uniqueStrings.add("three");

    uniqueStrings.add("one");
    uniqueStrings.add("two");
    uniqueStrings.add("three");

    System.out.println(uniqueStrings);
}
```

На выходе получим отсутствие дублей

```
[one, two, three]
```

Comment: Спасибо огромное, то что нужно

Answer (score 0):

проверяй каждый элемент indexOf!=lastIndexOf